# Route doesnt register

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this route registered:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Views", "View/{RouteID}", 
            new { controller = "BookingViewsPublicController", 
                action = "Index", RouteID = "" }
                );


        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
```

And I cant get like http://localhost:49764/View/Foo to work, I still have to go to /BookingViewsPublic/?RouteID=Foo for it to work. What might be wrong?

/M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I had the word "Controller" in the route, so BookingViewsPublic and NOT BookingViewsPublicController.

Answer (score 1):

*Resolved*

"BookingViewsPublic"  not "BookingViewsPublicController" in route-registration

Comment: Great to hear! Sometimes we do not need to look for complex solutions :)